# Count Data as an average of related events in a period of time

Tags: count-data, scales

I plan to run  a negative binomial regression on count data that I have. The thing I can't get my mind around is this:

Let's say the DV is how many days in the last 30 days people in Chicago bought ice cream. I want to know whether there is a difference between boys and girls in amount of ice cream purchased in that time period. I send out a survey that asks 3 questions.

1. "How many days in the last 30 did you buy ice cream sandwiches?"
2. "How many days in the last 30 did you buy a pint of ice cream?"
3. "How many days in the last 30 did you buy an ice cream cone?"

Assuming that these items are all correlated and that I have fully captured all types of ice cream purchases (which I obviously haven't, but work with me here), I want to take an average across these three questions and model the resulting DV as count data. I would want to exponentiate the outcome and be able to say something like "On average, boys bought 1.2x more ice cream than girls in the last 30 days."

**Problem is:** The average of these 3 items is likely to result in non-integer data. Am I still technically modeling count data if I take that average? Would negative binomial (or other models for count data) still be appropriate? 
Would it be more appropriate to try to model the sum of all three items, rather than the mean? Or should I go in an entirely different direction?

Thanks!

Comment: For a start is this really count data? The maximum is constrained by the data of the month. In principle the average taking can be done in the model by using an offset of log 3.

Comment: Thanks, @Björn. Do you mean that I can sort of model an average of the sum of the items by using an offset that is a column of log(3s) representing # of items?

I've seen elsewhere that, if the max of the observed data does not approach the upper bound, neg binomial can work. In my case, most variables at the item level seem to approximate a beta-binomial distribution (bounds at the top and bottom & overdispersed) but, when summed/when i take the mean, they seem to resemble a negative binomial distribution. Also, if I use a betabin distribution, won't that change interpretation dramatically?

Comment: @Björn I also asked a separate question that offers some specifics about my data, if that is helpful. [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297508/count-data-with-an-unmet-upper-limit-negative-binomial-vs-beta-binomial)